# How to plot specific data from a CSV file with matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib

From all the rows of a csv file, I want to keep only two arithmetic values from each row and use them as X-Y pairs for a plot I want to make and later to "feed" them on the code I wrote to cluster them. Any help?

Comment: First, learn `numpy`, then how to load csv into a numpy array.  Then it's trivial to select columns and plot them.  A bit about the clustering code might give us an idea of how much you already understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) to only load specific columns from a csv file, using `delimiter=','` and the `usecols` kwarg to select which columns to read.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a dummy csv file
from StringIO import StringIO
mycsv = StringIO("""
        1.,2.,3.,9.
        3.,4.,2.,4.
        8.,3.,4.,1.
        1.,6.,3.,4.
        """)

# Read csv using genfromtxt. Select only the second and firth columns.
x, y = np.genfromtxt(mycsv, usecols=(1, 3), unpack=True, delimiter=',')

plt.plot(x, y, 'ko')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's CSV module and list indexing to extract data and store them in lists.

I find this website's tutorial very enlightening: https://pythonprogramming.net/reading-csv-files-python-3/

You can use the **plt.scatter()** method to plot the data.

```
import matplotlib.pytplot as plt

plt.scatter(x,y) # x and y being 2 lists of the coordinates of your values
plt.show()
```